# iOS4 - trying to change a string value

Tags: ios4

I need to change a string value if it meets certain criteria, but I'm not having any luck so far.  I'm not sure if it's the input string or if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong - here's my code:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableString *stadium = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[prefs stringForKey:@"stadiumname"]]; 

NSLog(@"stadium: %@", stadium);  


if([prefs stringForKey:@"stadiumname"]==@"Brighton & Hove")
{
    [stadium setString:@"Hove"];
}

if([prefs stringForKey:@"stadiumname"]==@"Monmore Green")
{
    [stadium setString:@"Monmore"];
}

NSLog(@"stadium: %@", stadium);
```

In the NSLog output on both sides I still get "Brighton & Hove" or "Monmore Green", rather than just "Hove" or "Monmore" as I was expecting.  I've tried changing the input field to allow for possible encoding by doing:

```
NSMutableString *stadium = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[[prefs stringForKey:@"stadiumname"] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

but that makes no difference.  Would NSLog show up any encoding in the string anyway?

I just need to be able to use the shortened string once it comes out the other side, but so far no luck.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because of how you compare the string, so instead of

```
if([prefs stringForKey:@"stadiumname"]==@"Brighton & Hove")
```

use

```
if([[prefs stringForKey:@"stadiumname"] isEqualToString:@"Brighton & Hove"])
```

Comment: blimey, you answered that while I was still faffing about with the tags! You're right of course - I'll mark as an answer as soon as it lets me

Comment: well, this is a quite common mistake I would say, glad I could be any help!